# How can I add white gaussian noise to get the required extinction ratio?

Tags: noise, signal-power

I need to add white gaussian noise to my signal in MATLAB so that I obtain 15 dB extinction ratio (ER). I know that ER is max power level to min power level. I use below code to calculate my signal power. I appreciate if someone could explain to me how I can obtain noise power.

```
X = fft(sig);    
Px = sum((X).*conj(X))/((length(sig))^2);
```

**Update**
Then I use below code to add noise to my signal.

```
ER = 15; 
Py = 10^(-ER/10) * Px;  
sigma = sqrt(Py);
noise = sigma * randn(size(sig));
Sig_Nsy = sig + noise;
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $P_x$ as the power with the light source on, the power level with the light source off to be -15 dB lower would be $P_y = P_x 10^{-15/10}$.

This is with the understanding that the Extinction Ratio is the noise power generated by a laser diode when the light source is on compared to when the light source is off. The OP has computed the noise  power with the light source on as Px, and seeks the noise power with the light source off to be 15 dB lower, modeled as white Gaussian noise.

A noise power that is 15 dB lower is $10^{-15/10}$ by converting from dB to a power quantity as $dB = 10Log_{10}(P)$.

With $P_y$ established, the square root of $P_y$  would be the standard deviation $\sigma_y$ for the Gaussian white noise.  $$\sigma_y = \sqrt{P_y} = \sqrt{P_x}(10^{-15/20})$$

As an example in Matlab assuming $P_x$ was 5, the generation of a column vector of 500,000 samples of the Gaussian noise with would be as follows:

```
nsamps = 500000
sigma_y = sqrt(5) * 10^(-15/20);
p_y = sigma_y * randn(nsamps, 1);
```

To confirm the SNR, we can take the variance of the generated sequence (which is its power qty for the noise) and compare that to the power Px for the signal (5) to determine the difference in dB as 10Log(power_ratio):

```
10 * log10 ( 5 / var(p_y))
```

Which should return approximately 15 dB.

Comment: Thank you so much Dan for your answer! How can I get SNR? And how can I check if I get the correct Extinction ratio in Matlab?

Comment: @Amy sure - are you using Matlab or Python to create your noise signal?

Comment: I am using Matlab

Comment: How to check Extinction ratio?

Comment: In your code randn will return a matrix, but I think you just want a single vector. Compare to what I did where I specified nsamps rows and 1 column (randn(nsamps, 1)). Finally the last line that I added will give you the SNR, it should be approximately 15 dB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in this case ER and SNR are the same, since the off sate power determines noise power. Am I right?

Comment: @Amy I don't know that for certain, as I've seen some optical processes where the noise was proportional to signal level. To be clear, what I did here was answer how you can add noise that is 15 dB below your signal and that would be the SNR. If that is what you are trying to do then this would apply. If you are asking about optical electronics I can't answer that with confidence but that also would be a good question to post on the stack exchange electronics site.

Comment: Thanks Dan for all your help!